# Duplicate .class file in vs code

Tags: java, class, oop

The problem I am facing is that whenever I compile a .java file in my vscode it creates a .class file in my src folder of the project as well as one in the bin folder of the project.
I know that bin folder is the default folder for the .class file creation while compiling but I cannot understand why is it getting duplicated. I checked my setting json file has bin outpath but still I am facing this problem. Can someone tell me what might be the reason for this and how to troubleshoot.[Screenshot of the problem and the json file setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmpbE.png)

Comment: Look at using a better IDE for Java -- like IntelliJ.

Comment: @smac2020 There’s nothing wrong with VS Code. I’m using both IntelliJ IDEA and VS Code for Java development and although the latter is *mostly* less powerful (but note the “mostly”: one of the reasons why I’m using VS Code is because its remote working integration is second to none), it’s fundamentally a capable IDE for Java development.

Comment: Remove the .class files in your src folder, and try trigger the command `Java: Clean Java Language Server workspace`

Comment: @smac2020 vscode has many benefits compared to IntelliJ. It's lightweight, great for polyglot developers, always free, to name a few

Answer (score 0):

If you compile `stringcompare.java` via

```
javac stringcompare.java
```

then the `.class` files got duplicated. Try

```
javac -d bin src/stringcompare.java
```